# Axios is using NodeJS builtins in the ESM bundle for browser making it incompatible

Tags: javascript, webpack, axios, es6-modules, rollup

I'm creating a NPM library on the top of Axios. I'm generating two bundles, one "ESM" for browser and "CJS" for NodeJS with Rollup. However, the generated ESM module is importing some NodeJS build-in libraries like https, path and fs etc. As a result, the bundle is not usable in the frontend.

Additionally, I checked how Axios bundles the ESM bundle for the browser with rollup and found that there is a pollyfill mapping defined in the browser field of package.json for the NodeJS builtins. I tried to replicate same, but the error persists

```
"browser": {
    "node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js": "node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/null.js",
    "node_modules/axio/lib/platform/node/index.js": "node_modules/axios/lib/platform/browser/index.js"
  },
```

I also tried to use Rollup plugins for generating the polyfills for these default NodeJS builtins but it is not working. Could anyone help generate a browser compatible ESM bundle for a NPM library using Axios? I've attached the rollup configuration below

```
// rollup.config.js
const resolve = require('@rollup/plugin-node-resolve');
const commonjs = require('@rollup/plugin-commonjs');
const peerDepsExternal = require('rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external');
const typescript = require('@rollup/plugin-typescript');
const dts = require('rollup-plugin-dts');
const json = require('@rollup/plugin-json');

const packageJson = require('./package.json');

export default [
    {
        input: 'src/index.ts',
        output: [
            {
                file: packageJson.main,
                format: 'cjs',
            },
            {
                file: packageJson.module,
                format: 'esm',
            },
        ],
        plugins: [
            resolve(),
            commonjs(),
            json(),
            peerDepsExternal('./package.json'),
            typescript({ tsconfig: './tsconfig.json' }),
        ],
    },
    {
        input: 'dist/esm/index.d.ts',
        output: [{ file: 'dist/index.d.ts', format: 'esm' }],
        plugins: [dts.default()],
    },
];
```

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to keep the axios as a package dependency (Not peer dependency or dev dependency) but tell the rollup that it is external.

```
export default [
{
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [
        {
            file: packageJson.main,
            format: 'es',
        },
    ],
    external: ['axios'],
    plugins: [
        resolve({
           browser: true,
        }),
        commonjs(),
        json(),
        typescript({ tsconfig: './tsconfig.json' }),
    ],
},
...
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Spent hours figuring what went wrong and finally decided everything went haywire when I added axios in.